# Is there any way to search among scoped packages in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there any way to search among scoped packages? I have access to a private repository so I would like to see what packages are available there and try to figure out the package names. I totally understand that, if somebody doesn't have access to a repository then they mustn't see the content of it. But what about those who have access and would like to use it effectively?

Documentation doesn't help, however it is a basic scenario for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what branch you will be checking out. Anyway you could simply check out the main branch and look into the package.json file. Under dependencies there will be listed all the npm packages that the project is using. One other way would be to manually search through the node-modules folder.